# Where to Perform Authentication in REST API Server?

Tags: architecture, security, rest, server-security

I am working on a set of REST APIs that needs to be secured so that only authenticated calls will be performed. There will be multiple web apps to service these APIs. Is there a best-practice approach as to where the authentication should occur?

I have thought of two possible places.

1. Have each web app perform the authentication by using a shared authentication service. This seems to be in line with tools like Spring Security, which is configured at the web app level.
2. Protect each web app with a "gateway" for security. In this approach, the web app never receives unauthenticated calls. This seems to be the approach of Apache HTTP Server Authentication. With this approach, would you use Apache or nginx to protect it, or something else in between Apache/nginx and your web app?

For additional reference, the authentication is similar to services like AWS that have a non-secret identifier combined with a shared secret key. I am also considering using HMAC. Also, we are writing the web services in Java using Spring.

**Update:** To clarify, each request needs to be authenticated with the identifier and secret key. This is similar to how AWS REST requests work.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by Authentication in REST API Server? REST is stateless, so you don't authenticate only at the beginning of communication. If you meant authenticating every request, then usually it's only a simple function call.

Comment: I added an additional note that each request is authenticated.

Answer (score 2):

It is a matter of [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). In one case, a dedicated identity provider (IDP) does the authentication and provides an access token, which is verified by all web applications before a user (or an application) can execute an operation. In the other case, every web application has to do that authentication (even if they share the same code base).

The implications are significant esp. for consuming code:

- If there is one identity provider, a user (or the consuming code) will typically authenticate once, and the access token can then be supplied to as many web applications as needed. This enables single sign on (SSO) to be implemented across multiple domains (consider the case where a user logs in once to Facebook and then don't have to supply credentials for every site that uses FB authentication.)
- Since there is one IDP, all the user experience around logins is much easier to manage. For example, a user goes to a web application, it redirects to the IDP to login. The cases such as user forgetting user name, or password, or has some pre-requisite missing on their machine can all be handled by this common service. In the case of each web application doing this, somehow the authentication user experiences have to be exposed through each web application, which is doable, but more difficult to manage.
- There're already well-established protocols that you can use for such scenarios (e.g. [OAUTH](http://oauth.net/2/)), which means that you can use an external IDP (now or in the future) that supports the same protocol(s) without changing your application much.
- Since the specifications for such protocols are standardized, there is higher chance that one would get security right since important parameters are forced into the protocol (although there're still vulnerabilities that one has to manage, e.g. OAUTH is prone to [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) attacks as an example).

The benefit of each web application doing authentication is:

- Initial implementation is usually lower cost, because one does not have to deal with creating access tokens and passing them around and validating them. Once credentials are passed to a web application, it can make an internal call to a common library (or service) to validate the credentials. Usually, web development frameworks already provide some features to accomplish these so the cost is often very low.
- If all your apps are on one domain (and you can use cookies for single sign on), it is a far cleaner user experience (but as soon as you have two or more domains, the user experience becomes difficult esp. when there is no single sign on.)

Amazon, Microsoft, Facebook, Google, etc., all use a dedicated service because the pros are far more important for their users and consuming applications than the cost of implementing. In addition, they all have dedicated teams that work on authentication features such as automated password resets, multi-factor authentication, API access, as well as implementing newer protocols and improving existing one, esp. in terms of security.

[Disclaimer: I work at Microsoft in Active Directory and Security group. Opinions are my own, and I have made my best effort to make this response technology agnostic since it is a design question.]

Comment: Newbie oversight: After writing the response, I realized I am responding to almost a year old question!

Comment: this is a very helpful response to a year-old question. In the IDP case you described, are you saying that all traffic goes through the IDP, and then if authenticated, goes to the web app?

Answer (score 1):

The greatest concern IMHO is ease of use by developers, so assuming you are publishing an SDK or library as a compliment to your API, you can secure a client's calls any number of ways provided you keep it simple for the developer. But perhaps that is obvious?

That being said, I think the most straightforward way is HMAC. That gives you both the means to authenticate, but also the means by which you can verify the integrity of the message contents/payload. Plus, it is a common enough approach whereby most developers can find plenty of sample code to implement it for virtually any platform.

The question I might ask of you in return is, what is the data you need to secure? Are there any kind of industry standards you should conform to?

Otherwise, HTTP Basic auth over HTTPS only, or simply passing in a username/password parameters along with the request over HTTPS only might be sufficient (knowing full well though that this is not the most secure form of auth holistically speaking). Knowing that, if this is insufficient to your customers, you can always add additional forms of authentication down the road.

Comment: thanks for the response. I have a fairly good idea of how I'd like the authentication scheme to work. What I'm wanting to know, is where _on the server_ should the authentication verification occur. Within each webapp, or before the webapp is called?